# Is it possible to efficiently change the real domain zero-padding in the FFT domain?

Tags: fft

I have many medium-sized kernels (e.g. 20X20) I want to convolve with many images (e.g. 200X200). Ideally, I'd like to cache the convolution space version of the kernels to speed this up, but because of the necessary zero-padding the size of the FFT of the kernels could become a problem because of the difference in speed between CPU cache, RAM, and swap. Basically, the only way I can be certain caching will work is if there is an algorithm to change the real-space zero-padding of the FFT of an image that is faster than computing the FFT. Does such an algorithm exist, and how efficient is it compared to zero-pad then FFT?